# Change <label> text via <% JSP %>

Tags: jsp

```
<label id="MainText" ></label>

    <%

     out.println(mainBlog.getText()); %>
```

How can i connect the MainText Label with the mainBlog.getText() element?

Thanks.

Comment: Avoid use of scriptlets. Use proper tag library such as JSTL.

Answer (score 1):

```
<label id="MainText" ><%=mainBlog.getText()%></label>
```

This would work. But it's not a good practice to mix Java code in JSP.

Ideally you should set the `mainBlog` bean in request scope in java controller as an attribute

```
request.setAttribute("mainBlog",mainBlog);
```

and then use it in JSP using expression language

```
<label id="MainText" >${mainBlog.text}</label>
```